# Where to get the dhyana-Mantras of the eight Devis associated with Sri Yantra?

Tags: mantras, goddess, sri-vidya

Sri Yantra has various Devi-s associated with it.Their names are Tripura, Tripureshi, Tripurasundari,Tripuravasini,Tripurashri,Tripuramalini,Tripurasiddha,Tripuramba and Mahatripurasundari.

Where do we get the dhyana-mantras of these deities (i.e. the eight deities apart from Mahatripurasundari)?

Comment: In the question you said eight devis, but in the body you have mentioned nine names. Pls help us understand.

Answer (score 1):

A source that I am aware contains what you want is  Svacchanda paddhati (attributed to Cidānandanātha) which deals with the  navavāraṃ. The Devi names are indeed the names for each "president" Devi of those 9. From my point of view is the most extended text which gives details of all ( 1. tripurā 2. tripureśī 3. tripurasundarī 4. tripuravāsinī 5.
tripurāśrīḥ 6. tripuramālinī 7. tripurāsiddhā 8. tripurāmbā 9.
mahātripurasundarī as they are named also in kaula-upaniṣad ).
 Also
          1. tattvacintāmaṇi
          2. tripurārahasya māhatmyakaṇḍham
          3. nityāṣoḍaśikārṇavatantra
          4. parākramapūjā
          5. śrīvidyārṇavatantra
those 5 texts relate to dhyana-mantra of each 9. 
You can consult online the texts in transliterated forms from Sanskrit [here](http://muktalib5.org/digital_library_secure_entry.htm)

Comment: is that an answer or a comment?

Comment: Just_Do_It, is an answer, there are , in source text, all things OP asked.

Comment: Ok updated with link where OP can find the texts.